# How to make a specific view from an database object? Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to create an object with my database which I will then be able to click on and then it will be able to show a view that is only linked to the object.

I have created the database with Entity Framework. And made two models, should I tie them together, somehow?

```
public class Project
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Project")]
    public string Projects { get; set; }
    
    public int DisplayProject { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Tickets { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public int DisplayTicket { get; set; }
}
```

My idea is to be able to create a project that will then render a new view that you should be able to make tickets for

Comment: You would only tie them together if there's some sort of relationship between them. Based on what you've shown here there isn't relationship, but that doesn't mean we know everything about your project. What have you tried to accomplish your goal? Did you make action methods? Create views? What exact part are you stuck on? Why did you tag this as both asp.net and asp.net-core? They're separate frameworks.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC (on the "old", classic full .NET framework) - or ASP.NET **Core** MVC?? You have both tags - which is it you're using / targetting?

Comment: I have made two separate controllers. One for projects and one for tickets. Then I made it so that I could create a project that then highlights a button. On the button I want to bring out the specific view for the project I created. But when I then create a "ticket", it shows the same ticket for all projects

Comment: So the problem is that the tickets I create are displayed for ALL projects I create. When I only want to tie them to a specific project

Comment: Nothing in your code shows how the entities are related. Create a model with navigation properties first.

Comment: Thanks! How do i create navigation properties? Should i bring in project primary key in to ticket model ?

Comment: You'd start by going through EF Core tutorials and learning about navigation properties.

Comment: Like mentioned already, you have no relationships setup. You should do some research on EF about how it works. Sounds like your project class can have many tickets. So for example, your Project class could have a property of type IEnumerable<Ticket>. Then your Ticket class could have a property of type Project. You need to then know how to grab the data appropriately from the DB using EF when there are relationships. EX: _dbContect.Projects.Include(x => x.Tickets).ToList(); I recommend reading up on EF.

Comment: thanks! i just bought a course on udemy and hope it will give me a better insight into entity framwork :)